# select * from table where column = value ^ column2= value

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a login system in PHP. I need a user to use either his or her username or email or phone number to login then the password. since I know in java we would do like `email==user^ username == user` does this apply in MySQL. Could I do something like this in MySQL?

```
Select * from user WHERE mail = 'user' ^ phoneNo= 'user' ^ username = 'user' and password = 'pass'
```

I have tried it and it failed. Alternatively, I use multiple `if`s in PHP and check one at a time like this

```
if (mail == user){
}
```

Comment: where do you want to implement it? in php or sql?

Comment: try `or` instead of `^`. and use parenthesis

Comment: Do as suggested by @pala_ , I have also added it as an answer.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/non-typed-operators.html

Comment: I suppose it's impossible that one user's username could be another user's phone number? Or are passwords unique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query would be -

```
Select * from user WHERE (mail = 'user' or phoneNo= 'user' or username = 'user') and password = 'pass'
```

Or

```
Select * from user WHERE 'user' in (mail, phoneNo, username) and password = 'pass'
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's [`xor`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor) does what `^` does in Java, but both are incorrect in this case. You want a user with either the username, phone number or email equal to a given string. `xor` means that **only one of these can match**, while, by the question's text, it seems as though you'd also want users who have, e.g., both a `username` or a `mail` equal to `'user'`. For this usecase, a simple `or` operator should do the trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user 
WHERE  (mail = 'user' OR phoneNo = 'user' OR username = 'user') AND 
       password = 'pass'
```

Or, more elegantly, you could use the `in` operator as a shorthand for the series of `or`s:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user 
WHERE  'user' IN (mail, phoneNo, username) AND 
       password = 'pass'
```

Comment: The system must know whether it was a username or an email or a phone number that was passed. It would be horribly insecure otherwise!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (mail = 'user' OR phoneNo= 'user' OR username = 'user') AND password = 'pass';
```